# Good modularity in C++ using #define

Tags: c++, modularity

As the title says I'm looking for a good way to do modularity in C++ using #define. Let me explain.

I have a simple settings header file like such:

```
//Settings.h
define HTTP
```

And a include file:

```
//include.h
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#ifdef HTTP
#include "HTTPStuff.cpp"
#endif
```

Main file:

```
//Main.cpp
#include "Include\Includes.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string res = HTTP_POST_REQUEST("localhost", "/script.php", "data=data1");
    cout << res << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

The function HTTP_POST_REQUEST is inside HTTPStuff.cpp
This however makes a lot of errors popup when trying to run the program.
Like "missing ';' before identifier 'response'", and it all just seems weird to me.

If HTTP is defined, then include HTTPStuff.cpp which contains HTTP_POST_REQUEST.
I must be missing something, but what?

Comment: The general advises are: Avoid `#define`; Don't include .cpp files. Not  sure how special your case is.

Comment: This is for a project where it might consist of multiple people in a team, modular code would be great for this purpose, and it's easy to navigate. You got no ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Then, your case sounds typical and usual to me. Follow the general advise. You may look at some open source project for reference.

Comment: It's also a way to choose what gets compiled, so I can define which modules I want, and therefor customise the build how I want. Since what you are saying is just "general advice", that means that there is a way for what I want correct?

Comment: The way to choose what gets compiled is to tell your compiler to compile only what you want, not to go through some terrible `#include` contortions with your .cpp files.  How you tell your compiler what to compile will depend on your build system.

Comment: I guess you did not include "Setting.h" inside Main.cpp. You have to recheck the definition of  HTTP inside your main file and as recommendation never include *.cpp file

Comment: I might be wrong about the compiler thing. So I guess what I'm trying to do is not possible?

Comment: @Afshin Yeah it isn't included. But including it doesn't help, and the errors are still there. Setting.h is getting included through include.h though.

Comment: This a very strange way to go about what you need. If other people need to use these functions/classes make them a dynamic or static library and have others link to them. No compilation required.

Comment: have you used any directive (like #pragma once) to make sure that the inclusion occurs once??

Comment: Possible, yes. C++ allows you the freedom of doing horrible and stupid  things. One must strive to resist the urge to exercise this freedom. Look into configuring your development environment's build system to handle building different (keyword alert) targets.

Comment: I've seen this kind of thing in other C++ projects and I can't understand how they did it (can't really remember it well enough). Even if it's bad practice it would be great if anyone had a suggestion for what I'm trying to do exactly (without needing to go into any settings). @Afshin sadly #pragma once didn't seem to help.